# Pyinstaller ImportError without no details when compiling

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile my script into an exe file using PyInstaller, but I get the error ImportError with no details or specifics. Just ImportError.

The following is the entire terminal output

```
C:\Users\vk2458\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts>pyinstaller C:\Users\vk2458\PycharmProjects\untitled\Excelmagic.py
101 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.1
101 INFO: Python: 3.5.5
102 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
105 INFO: wrote C:\Users\vk2458\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\Excelmagic.spec
108 INFO: UPX is not available.
111 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\vk2458\\PycharmProjects\\untitled',
 'C:\\Users\\vk2458\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\Scripts']
111 INFO: checking Analysis
111 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
111 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
116 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
121 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5046 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
5049 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\python.exe
5559 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\vk2458\PycharmProjects\untitled\Excelmagic.py
6190 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
7421 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
11625 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
11626 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\vk2458\\appdata\\local\\continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
69940 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
118851 INFO: Looking for import hooks ...
118855 INFO: Processing hook   hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py
118858 INFO: Processing hook   hook-sqlite3.py
118864 INFO: Processing hook   hook-win32com.py
119122 INFO: Processing hook   hook-IPython.py
126273 INFO: Processing hook   hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py
126274 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pycparser.py
126519 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt5.QtSvg.py
126520 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pywintypes.py
127723 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.py
127739 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
127751 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide
127753 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide.qRgba
127753 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide.QImage
127753 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide.QPixmap
127753 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
127754 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
127767 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4
127769 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QImage
127769 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.qRgba
127769 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QPixmap
127769 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
127783 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5.QtGui.QImage
127783 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5.QtCore.QIODevice
127785 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5.QtGui.qRgba
127785 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5.QtGui.QPixmap
127786 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5.QtCore
127786 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5.QtCore.QBuffer
127786 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5.QtGui
127786 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
127800 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.Image.py
129126 INFO: Processing hook   hook-jinja2.py
129142 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py
129144 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.py
129144 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt5.py
129147 INFO: Processing hook   hook-sphinx.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 683, in get_module_file_attribute
    attr = loader.get_filename(package)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_filename'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\vk2458\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 755, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 701, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 183, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 432, in assemble
    imphook_object = ImportHook(imported_name, hook_file)
  File "c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 182, in __init__
    self._module = importlib_load_source(hook_modname, self._filename)
  File "c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 490, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 418, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 841, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 700, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 268, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 693, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 697, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-sphinx.py", line 84, in <module>
    datas.extend(collect_data_files('sphinx_rtd_theme'))
  File "c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 1084, in collect_data_files
    pkg_base, pkg_dir = get_package_paths(package)
  File "c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 932, in get_package_paths
    file_attr = get_module_file_attribute(package)
  File "c:\users\vk2458\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 693, in get_module_file_attribute
    raise ImportError
ImportError
```

I haven't been able to figure out where to look since I don't get any details or specifics regarding what causes the error. The modules I'm importing in the script are sys, PyQt5, Pandas, datetime, and enum.

Comment: `ImportError: No module named 'sphinx_rtd_theme'`

Comment: installing that specific module seems to have solved the problem. I see now that I should start reading through the terminal outputs myself thoroughly before asking for help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to your terminal output, it is looking for a module that does not exist:

`ImportError: No module named 'sphinx_rtd_theme'`